# Pandas - Replacing Nulls with the most frequent value from groups

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset containing the following columns:

```
['sex', 'age', 'relationship_status]
```

There are some NaN values in 'relationship_status' column and I want to replace them with the most common value in each group based on age and gender.

I know how to groupby and count the values:

```py
df2.groupby(['age','sex'])['relationship_status'].value_counts()
```

and it returns:

```
age   sex     relationship_status
17.0  female  Married with kids       1
18.0  female  In relationship         5
              Married                 4
              Single                  4
              Married with kids       2
      male    In relationship         9
              Single                  5
              Married                 4
              Married with kids       4
              Divorced                3
.
.
.

86.0  female  In relationship         1
92.0  male    Married                 1
97.0  male    In relationship         1
```

So again, what I need to achieve is that whenever "relationship_status" is empty I need the program to replace it with the most frequent value based on persons age and gender.

Can anyone suggest how can I do it?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this, it returns 'ALL_NAN' when within (age,sex) subgroups are only nans:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'age': [25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25,],
         'sex': ['F', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', ],
         'status': ['married', np.nan, 'married', np.nan, np.nan, 'single']
        })


df.loc[df['status'].isna(), 'status'] = df.groupby(['age','sex'])['status'].transform(lambda x: x.mode()[0] if any(x.mode()) else 'ALL_NAN')
```

Output:

```
   age sex   status
0   25   F  married
1   25   F  married
2   25   F  married
3   25   M   single
4   25   M   single
5   25   M   single
```

Comment: This version for didnt work aswell, it returned `IndexError: index out of bounds`. Thanks for submiting though.

Comment: Check it on your data, small change that should fix it: `lambda x: x.mode()[0] if any(x.mode()) else 'ALL_NAN'`

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I have also found a simillar solution if anyone is interested:

`df2["relationship_status"] = df2.groupby(['age','sex'])['relationship_status'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode()[0] if not x.mode().empty 
                                                                                                      else "Empty"))`

Comment: mode().empty is more clean and better :) Please upvote/accept my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
mode = df2.groupby(['age','sex'])['relationship_status'].agg(lambda x: pd.Series.mode(x)[0])
df2['relationship_status'].fillna(mode, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Hey @John-Zwinck,
Thanks for your answer.

It doesnt however seem to work. When I run the first line by itself it returns:

`IndexError: index out of bounds`

When I changed (lambda x: pd.Series.mode(x)[0]) to (lambda x: pd.Series.mode(x)) it worked, but then the second line returns an error:

`ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'Python object' but got 'long'`

This is probably because the mode method recognized in some cases multiple values as a mode like in this case:

`77.0  female    [Divorced, Married, Married with kids]`

Any idea how to proceed with this?

Comment: It sounds like some ages+sexes have all their relationship status values as NaN.  You'll need to decide what to do about that and put it in the lambda.  For example you could change the lambda to a regular function and do whatever you want if the mode is empty.